# Cannot connect to Unity3D master server from another device(computer)

Tags: c#, networking, unity-game-engine

I'm making an online FPS. Now I have a workable client & server system on my local machine. I'm trying to make my Mac act as the master server.

I download the Master Server and Facilitator. I compiled them and it looks like that they are working. I check it through the Unity3D's window and on the build of my game - on my computer master server creates a game and client can connect to it, but when I try to connect to the master server from another computer (not my Mac) it shows me an error :

> "Cannot connect to master server (my ip here). Is it working?"

**How can I fix it?**
All processes are working (Master Server & facilitator. The facilitator also shows my connections from my computer, not from others)

**The server setup code :**

```
// Use this for initialization
void Awake () {
    MasterServer.ipAddress = "my ip address";
    MasterServer.port = 23466;

    Network.natFacilitatorIP = "my ip address ";
    Network.natFacilitatorPort = 50005;
}

void OnGUI() {
    if (GUILayout.Button("create server")) {
        Network.InitializeServer(4, port, true); //SHOWS ERROR FROM OTHER DEVICES
        MasterServer.RegisterHost(gameType,mapName); //SO DOES IT
    }

    if (GUILayout.Button("connect")) {
        Network.Connect(data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Any firewalls and the like that might be stopping you?

Comment: @Bart nope, I gave full access to app